# Pandas dataframe join using mutiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a dataframe outer join using multiple columns:

DF1:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1          2      3        4
1          2      3        4
```

DF2:

```
ColumnE ColumnF ColumnG ColumnH
1          2      3        4
1          2      3        4
```

Merging code:

```
df= pd.merge(DF1, DF2, left_on=['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD'], right_on=['ColumnE','ColumnF','ColumnG','ColumnH'], how='outer')
```

Actual outcome:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE ColumnF ColumnG ColumnH
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
```

Expected outcome(the values should display only twice as the combination of columns matches exactly in two datasets):

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE ColumnF ColumnG ColumnH
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
1        2       3       4         1      2       3       4
```

Can someone advise where am I going wrong?

Comment: This happens because there are duplicate values ​​in each column. If your data frame had 3 rows instead of 2 then 9 rows would appear instead of 4. please check my answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identical duplicates on both `df1` and `df2`, so the merged `df` got number of rows double for each duplicate. Simple solution is keep one dataframe unique by `drop_duplicates` and `merge`

```
df = pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), df2, left_on=['ColumnA','ColumnB' ,'ColumnC','ColumnD'], right_on=['ColumnE','ColumnF','ColumnG','ColumnH'], how='outer')

Out[742]:
   ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD  ColumnE  ColumnF  ColumnG  ColumnH
0        1        2        3        4        1        2        3        4
1        1        2        3        4        1        2        3        4
```

Answer (score 2):

So we need `merge` with a additional  key , created by `cumcount`

```
df1=df1.assign(Key=df1.groupby(list(df1)).cumcount())
df2=df2.assign(Key=df1.groupby(list(df1)).cumcount()

df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD','Key'],
               right_on=['ColumnE','ColumnF','ColumnG','ColumnH','Key'], how='outer')
Out[19]: 
   ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD  Key  ColumnE  ColumnF  ColumnG  ColumnH
0        1        2        3        4    0        1        2        3        4
1        1        2        3        4    1        1        2        3        4
```

Comment: I never think about adding an additional key :) +1